# Do collection instances use less memory than duplicates?

Tags: modifiers, collections, memory-management

I can't find a straightforward answer to this anywhere. I just wanna know what the fastest way to view multiple objects is.

Comment: Hello :). The difference in render speed is negligible, the memory usage is the same for both. Keep in mind that memory usage and render speed are not directly related.

Comment: Thank you! Here is some filler text to post a comment